# Rules for creating a custom tensorflow Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

there is a great introduction of [how to create custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers) in tensorflow.

An example, taken from the documentation, would be

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
                                  shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                                         self.num_outputs])

  def call(self, input):
    return tf.matmul(input, self.kernel)

layer = MyDenseLayer(10)
```

I would like to know, which options I have to create the layers without getting into a conflict with the backpropagation engine.

Am I allowed to use

```
1. **numpy** statements
2. **if/else** statements
3. **for** loops
4. **lists and dictionaries*
```

I assume, using numpy is difficult, but can I use the tensorflow counterpart in e.g. a for loop?

If you can give additional rules, feel free to add them.

Comment: You can use TensorFlow operations and also loops and if/else if you need them. About lists and dictionaries, it depends on what use you are thinking of. You should not convert a tensor into a list, for example. NumPy operations should be avoided, you can use them in eager mode, but gradients will not backpropagate through them, and the function will not be "traced" into a graph, making it slower. In general, doing whatever you can do in a [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) should work (see [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function)).

Comment: You could use NumPy functions through [`tf.numpy_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function), but that will still not give you a gradient, unless you provide it yourself e.g. by wrapping it with a [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient).